# IllegalArgumentException: Unrecognized scheme null; expected s3, s3n, or s3a

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, aws-glue

I want to Write the dynamic frame into my redshift, but i got error that says

> Unrecognized scheme null; expected s3, s3n, or s3a

i have tried like this below.

```
sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)

datasource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "data_input", table_name = "db_public_trx", transformation_ctx = "datasource0")

datasource1 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "data_output", table_name = "redshiftdev_public_trx", transformation_ctx = "datasource1")

src_df =  datasource0.toDF()

dst_df =  datasource1.toDF()

merged_df = dst_df.union(src_df)

datasource3 = fromDF(merged_df,glueContext,"datasource3")

datasink = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(frame = datasource3, database = "data_output", table_name = "redshiftdev_public_trx", redshift_tmp_dir = args["TempDir"], transformation_ctx = "datasink")
job.commit()
```

Comment: Are you running this locally or in Glue?

Comment: I'm running this on Glue

Comment: Do you provide TempDir as job argument?